# string index out of range error - TBRPG - python

Tags: python-3.x

ok, so i'm creating a rpg and i keep on getting this string error out of range thing

```
while playerturn1[0] != playerturn and playerturn1[1] != playerturn and playerturn[2]
!= playerturn:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

[here is all the code so far](http://snipt.org/yhXg2)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you meant to write

```
playerturn1[2]
```

instead of

```
playerturn[2]
```

Be sure to use clearly distinguishable variable names in order to avoid such mistakes.